# Set the title of an UIPopOver View Programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do you set the title of an UIPopOver View programmatically?

I found some sample code but wasn't able to set the title.

```
myView *theView = [[myView alloc] initWithNibName:@"myView" 
                                       bundle:nil];
UIPopoverController* aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:theView];
[aPopover setDelegate:self];
[aPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320) animated:YES];

[theView setPopover:aPopover];
[theView release];

[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(510,370,0,0) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: I am not sure, but searching google around tells me that it can not have a title

Comment: It's everywhere. For example the Mail app in portrait mode. The popover window shows your emails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to wrap the view controller in a `UINavigationCotnroller` which will add a navigation bar with the appropriate title for the view controller. Something like this:

```
UINavigationController *container =
    [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController] autorelease];
```

Then just initialize your popover to use `container` instead and present it as usual.

Comment: It doesn't look the same if you add the nav bar from IB.

Comment: Ah of course... yeah the popover modifies the nav controller to look black and translucent. So you should wrap the view controller in a navigation controller.

Comment: add view to nav controller then add nav controller to popover controller then set title for nav controller?

Answer (score 4):

yes, exactly. the whole thing could look like this:

```
InfoView *infoView = [[InfoView alloc] init];
UINavigationController *container = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoView] autorelease];
UIPopoverController *pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:container];

infoView.title = @"My Title";

[pop setDelegate:self];
[pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 400)];
[pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
[infoView release];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let popoverContent = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Popover"))! as UIViewController
popoverContent.title = "Details"
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
let popover = nav.popoverPresentationController
popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100)
popover!.delegate = self
popover!.sourceView = self.view
popover!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100,100,0,0)

self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the title of the contentViewController of your popOver:

```
theView.title = @"My Title";
```

or

theView.navigationItem.title = @"My Title";